# Blazor app with ASP.NET Identity UI shared layuout template

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a default Blazor application with a MainLayout.cshtml file. created as follows;

```
- MyBlazorApp/
-- Shared/
--- MainLayout.cshtml
```

Within this application I have scaffolded various ASP.NET Identity pages (login, logout etc), which have their own structure and a `_layout.cshtml` template created as follows;

```
- MyBlazorApp
-- Areas/
--- Identity/
---- Pages/
----- _ViewStart.cshtml  <-- references "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
-- Pages/
--- Shared/
---- _layout.cshtml
```

I want to have one template file that both applications use. Which way round should this be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The Blazor's lay out, MainLayout is a component whose file name's extension is `.razor` (MainLayout.razor ). On the other hand, _Layout.cshtml is a Razor Page... As you can embed a razor component in a Razor Page, you can embed the MainLayout in _Layout.cshtml. But this it...

Comment: Do you know if anything changed with .NET5? I find it hard to believe that you can't integrate something as basic as Identity into Blazor with a major duplication of effort.

Comment: By the way, the email address in your profile page doesn't seem to work any more. Bounced back with an error saying the address didn't exist at the domain. My fault for being naughty and sending you a private email! Your fault for putting your email there! 

Comment: "Do you know if anything changed with .NET5?" Not related to the version of .Net. He wants to have a single file that is shared by Blazor and the Razor Pages of Identity UI. This is inherently not possible as two types on frameworks are involved. You can embed a Blazor component in a Razor page, as for instance, the App component is embedded in the Razor Pages page ( _Host.cshtml ), and is renderd as the Blazor application. But you can't have this the other way around.

Comment: You can't embed a Razor Pages page in a Blazor component, thus creating a component or whatever that two type of framework can share is not possible.

Comment: " I find it hard to believe that you can't integrate something as basic as Identity into Blazor with a major duplication of effort" It's not related to Identity or other API. Depending on the structure of your application, you may do a lot, but once again, you cannot integrate Razor Pages pages in your components. You can access  Razor Pages pages such as Login or logout through navigation out of the SPA space, using an anchor element or NavigationManger.NavigateTo, but this takes you out of the SPA boundaries.

Comment: @Mark Cooper, did you ask this question because you want, for example, to display the Login page within the Blazor Application ? If your question is about appearance, then the best solution is to design the _layout.cshtml to  look the same as the MainLaout.razor, with the same colors, text images, etc., and when the user click on the Login button it would look like the Login page is part of the Blazor App.

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel, not sure what you mean ? Did you previously click on my email, and was able to send me email, and now you can't ? You did send me an email, right ? I guess you copied my email , and then pasted it in your email editor, no ? My email is there and whomever want to post me an email can copy and post it into his email editor.

Comment: I think my point was that when you scaffold Identity into an MVC project, you get MVC-based code. When you scaffold into a Razor pages project you get Razor pages based code. I was expecting that when you scaffold into a Blazor project, you'd get Blazor components, not Razor pages. I wouldn't have thought it was such a difficult thing to provide these.

Comment: Re email. I sent you another which didn't bounce back. Please can you reply and let me know if you got it.

Comment: "I wouldn't have thought it was such a difficult thing to provide these" Not difficult but requires a great deal of investment in terms of programmers and money. Microsoft will never do such a thing, especially because there are other ways to preform authentication and authorization, depending on the design of your app, what flavor of Blazor it is, is it hosted on the cloud, does it uses Azure AD, and plenty of other factors... I've seen some programmers trying to design Razor components for some functionality provided by the Identity UI, but soon enough they give up.